# Convert Multiple Columns to One Large Column (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to convert 15,096 columns of text (one word per cell) to one large column including every cell from the original columns.  My original columns vary in size (i.e. one column may have 4 cells/rows, while another may have 100 cells/rows).

I have no experience with VBA, but have recorded a macro to do this somewhat manually and it is taking forever.  Please help with something that I could set and go get coffee and come back to see the job done.  (NOTE: Some columns have 1 word/row...this has made my macro throw an error every time it encounters one of these).

Thank you! Hope someone can help.
-Mike

Comment: Bear in mind that Excel can only have up to 32,767 characters per cell (I think this is still true for 2010) so if your text exceeds this you'll run into problems.

Comment: Still correct, with only 1024 characters displaying in the cell.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm analyzing a set of survey comments and I would like to know the top 10 words (sort of SEOish).  Once I have 1 column I can use an array formula to get the first of that top 10, then cleanse and repeat.  I'm not that technical, so this could probably be done with an array through VBA. All recommendations welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all your cells aligned in one column, you can use this code:

```
Sub ToArrayAndBack()
Dim arr As Variant, lLoop1 As Long, lLoop2 As Long
Dim arr2 As Variant, lIndex As Long

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


ReDim arr2(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count - ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count)

arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value


For lLoop1 = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For lLoop2 = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If Len(Trim(arr(lLoop1, lLoop2))) > 0 Then
            arr2(lIndex) = arr(lLoop1, lLoop2)
            lIndex = lIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Sheets.Add
Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Value = arr2

Range("A1").Resize(, lIndex + 1).Copy
Range("A2").Resize(lIndex + 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Rows(1).Delete

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

If you want to concatenate each row, use this instead. It will consolidate your cells in a new sheet.

```
Sub Consolidate()
Dim shtDest As Worksheet, shtOrg As Worksheet
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastCol As Long, lLoop As Long
Dim sFormula  As String

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
lLastCol = shtOrg.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lLastRow = shtOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set shtDest = Sheets.Add

For lLoop = 1 To lLastCol
    sFormula = sFormula & "'" & shtOrg.Name & "'!RC" & lLoop & ","
Next lLoop

sFormula = Left(sFormula, Len(sFormula) - 1)

shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=concatenate(" & sFormula & ")"
shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).Value = shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).Value


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

or if you want your cells separated by spaces

```
Sub Consolidate()
Dim shtDest As Worksheet, shtOrg As Worksheet
Dim lLastRow As Long, lLastCol As Long, lLoop As Long
Dim sFormula  As String

Const sSeparator As String = " "

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With


Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
lLastCol = shtOrg.UsedRange.Columns.Count
lLastRow = shtOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set shtDest = Sheets.Add

For lLoop = 1 To lLastCol
    sFormula = sFormula & "'" & shtOrg.Name & "'!RC" & lLoop & "&""" & sSeparator & ""","
Next lLoop

sFormula = Left(sFormula, Len(sFormula) - 1)

shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=trim(concatenate(" & sFormula & "))"
shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).Value = shtDest.Range("A1:A" & lLastRow).Value


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: +1 definitely a good answer. You might be able to speed it up slightly by storing shtOrg.Name to a variable instead of retrieving it for each iteration of the loop, but the gain would negligible.

Comment: The effect of the code puts concatenates the rows of each column.  I was wanting to take the columns and stack them effectively creating one large column. If you had 10 columns with different row counts--> 1 column with 4 rows, then 5 columns with 6 rows, then 4 columns with 3 rows.  The Macro should stack each of those resulting in 1 column with 46 rows.  I'm using this to determine what my top 10 words are in a medium size data set of surveys.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MultiColsToA() 
Dim rCell As Range 
Dim lRows As Long 
Dim lCols As Long 
Dim lCol As Long 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim wsNew As Worksheet 

lCols = Columns.Count 
lRows = Rows.Count 
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add() 

For Each ws In Worksheets 
    With ws 
        For Each rCell In .Range("B1", .Cells(1, lCols).End(xlToLeft)) 
            .Range(rCell, .Cells(lRows, rCell.Column).End(xlUp)).Cut _ 
            wsNew.Cells(lRows, 1).End(xlUp)(2, 1) 
        Next rCell 
    End With 
Next ws 

End Sub
```

Comment: That's still going to be pretty darn slow leaving the screenupdating and the calcs

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your recorded macro and insert this line at the top:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Then set screenUpdating back to true at the bottom of your code. This should dramatically speed up the code as it prevents the macro from visually showing you the changes after every single change. This avoids many many calls to graphics, which slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.  This joins all the strings in the row and puts the resulting string in the first cell of the row.  That means that anything that was in that cell will be overwritten.  *That* means that you should try this on a copy of your workbook because if it doesn't do what you want you will have lost data.

```
Sub MakeOneColumn()

    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim vaRow As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aJoin() As Variant

    'Loop through each row in the sheet
    For Each rRow In Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows

        'put the rows values in an array
        vaRow = rRow.Value

        'Convert the array from 2-d to 1-d because the Join function needs 1-d
        ReDim aJoin(LBound(vaRow, 2) To UBound(vaRow, 2))
        For i = LBound(vaRow, 2) To UBound(vaRow, 2)
            aJoin(i) = vaRow(1, i)
        Next i

        'Join the array into one string, replace double spaces, and write to the
        'first cell in the row (replacing what was there - so be careful)
        rRow.Cells(1).Value = Replace(Join(aJoin, Space(1)), Space(2), Space(1))
    Next rRow

End Sub
```